# How to display laptop charging speed

Tags: power-management, usb-c

I have a laptop that charges via USB-C and it can be charged by connecting it to the USB-C port of my desktop. But I would like to know at which wattage.

Is there a command to display at which wattage a laptop is charging? This might also be helpful when comparing different charging bricks and USB cables.

Comment: This isn't a full answer... but... usually the wattage is simply listed on the charging brick. E.g., my USB-C charger says 65W on the side, and that would be the max for the charger. This wouldn't be helpful to you, but is a reasonable general answer. As to getting the _current_ power draw in software, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10418) on Unix & Linux SE.

Comment: cocomac: My question was about charging via the usb-c port on my desktop, so it's not as obvious where to look it up as a charging brick. But even  with a charging brick it's nice to be able to verify how much wattage actually goes through, since it also depends on the cable which normally doesn't  have any label.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to try **battop** utility which can be installed by downloading from [Project GitHub page](https://github.com/svartalf/rust-battop/releases) prepackaged for your distribution.

Install tool by command

```
sudo install battop-* /usr/local/bin/battop
```

You run `$battop` and see many useful battery related info including estimated charging time.

Comment: The tool is no longer maintained, but maybe it is feature-complete. The [GNU binary](https://github.com/svartalf/rust-battop/releases/download/v0.2.4/battop-v0.2.4-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) worked on Fedora 38 as well.